# Facebook native app not loading my app request correctly - Android

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-requests

Thanks for reading my question.
I'm not sure that this error is on my or Facebooks end but I'll ask just to be sure.

The issue I'm facing is that when I send a request to a friend from my native app the friend receives the request as a notification on his Android phone (Correct). When he clicks the notification from the Facebook-app the Facebook-app opens as it should but when it's open it just shows a loading screen forever. I want it to go to Google Play to my app there. Or to any page specified on my Facebook settings for that matter.

The weird thing is that if you have the Facebook app opened when receiving the request and click on the top drop down bar where the notifications are stored and click on the notification/request there it goes to Google Play like it should.

In my Facebook-settings for my app I've set the Canvas URL, the Site URL, The Android package name to Google Play and enabled Facebook Login and Deep Linking.

Is there anything else I can do here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okey I solved it.
I solved it by checking the "Mobile Web" option on Facebook settings and then putting a url there. (Same as my Canvas URL). Weirdly Facebook uses the notification purely as a link to this page.

I then used that page to redirect users to the Google Play page if the device was an Android. And finally the user got to the app on Google Play. Very strange that Facebook could not use a fallback if this option isn't checked.

Comment: unable to find "Mobile Web" option in application page on developer side.

Comment: @Ajay I think it might have changed to under "Website" and the "
"Mobile Site URL"